# Shorthand for getting the diff from the last N commits?

Tags: git

I know I can do:

```
git diff HEAD^..HEAD
```

But is there some shorthand that's easier to remember, like:

```
git diff foo N
```

where `N` can be any number of commits from now to get a cumulative diff of?

Answer (score 42):

From the [SPECIFYING REVISIONS of the `git rev-parse` man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html#_specifying_revisions):

> A suffix `~<n>` to a revision parameter means the commit object that is the `<n>`th generation grand-parent of the named commit object, following only the first parent.
>   I.e. `rev~3` is equivalent to `rev^^^` which is equivalent to `rev^1^1^1`.

Consider the examples in the [`git diff` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

```
git diff HEAD^..HEAD
git diff HEAD^..
git diff HEAD^ HEAD
```

are equivalent forms (thanks [chrisk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54401/chrisk) for the `HEAD^..` form, as mentioned in the comments).
(they are not equivalent to `git diff HEAD^`, as [Mark Longair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223092/mark-longair) comments, since it `diff` with the working directory, not the last commit)

So:

```
git diff HEAD~15       # diff the working tree with the 15th previous commit
git diff HEAD~15 HEAD  # diff the last commit  with the 15th previous commit
```

should do what you need (as [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) mentions in the comment).

Comment: Just a small point: `git diff HEAD^ HEAD` and `git diff HEAD^` aren't equivalent - the latter shows the changes between `HEAD^` and your working tree.  I guess from the question (although it's not quite clear) that he wants `git diff HEAD~15 HEAD`.

Comment: When you use a range notation, but omit the ref on one side, it'll use `HEAD` as the default. So `git diff HEAD~15..` is a shorter alternative.

Answer (score 15):

Use `git diff HEAD~N`. Or use `git diff HEAD~N..` to exclude uncommitted changes.

Comment: Just thought the other answer was a bit verbose.